# How to create a WebControl from plain text

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I have a TableCell "cell", where "cell.Text" contains something like

```
"<input type=\"checkbox\" tabindex=\"-1\" style=\"height:17px\" checked=\"checked\" />".
```

Goal is to remove the style property "height"!

Plse. note that the "style" attribute can contain some other properties (like "backgroundColor", etc.) 
and that whitspaces can be used between "height:" and the value (here "17px") 
and that it can (but must not) be terminated with a ";"
etc ... 
So it makes no sense to me to parse it (using ".Substring(...)" etc.).

Another possible way would be to create a WebControl and to use ".Remove(...)".

Nice idea, but not working:

```
    var control = Page.ParseControl(cell.Text);
    var tmpPage = new Page();
    tmpPage.Controls.Add(control);

    var webControl = tmpPage.Controls[0] as WebControl; // this return null because "Control" could not be casted to WebControl

    var before = webControl.Style;
    webControl.Style.Remove(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height);
    var after = webControl.Style;
```

But this doesnt work. See my comment.

How to reach my goal?

Thx in advance.

Comment: no one no idea? ... :-(

Comment: Not the best way. But you can try remove by regular expression: Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("<input type=\"checkbox\" tabindex=\"-1\" style=\"height:17px;\" checked=\"checked\" />", @"height:\s?\d+px;?", ""));

Comment: Thx! Good idea! Will try it after adjusting your idea a little bit because "px" can also be "em" or "%" and be terminated with a ";" or even not ... Can you please help me to adjust your reg expression?

in the meanwhile is solved it this way: cell.Text = cell.Text.Replace("height:", "dummy:");

Comment: Adjusted it myself ;-) This works fine for me: cell.Text = Regex.Replace(cell.Text, @"height:\s?\d+(px|em|%);?\s?", "");